# Grid template columns not correctly formed

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am not so similar with grid. I usually use flex. I have a navbar, side menu and content.

The content here I marked with a yellow background. This should take the whole height of the page right below the navbar. What am I doing wrong?

I tried setting the content div `height: 100%;` but it does nothing.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/vigorous-albattani-1cjjts?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A46%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A5%2C%22startColumn%22%3A46%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A5%7D%5D

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the value of your `grid-area` in your `.grid-container-content` class. and you should use `grid-area: 2 / 2 / span 2;`. I add a reference *[here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-area.php)* so you can learn more about griding

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  grid-template-columns: 225px auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "sidebar navbar"
    "sidebar content";
}

.grid-container-navbar {
  background-color: #131722;
  height: 40px;
}

.grid-container-sidebar {
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  background-color: #131722;
  grid-area: sidebar;
  height: inherit;
}

.grid-container-content {
  height: 100%;
  /* grid-area: content; */
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / span 2;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
   <div class="grid-container-navbar"></div>
   <div class="grid-container-sidebar"></div>
   <div class="grid-container-content"></div>
</div>
```